# Automatically display on-screen keyboard for all form items in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, accessibility

I'm trying to write a only touchscreen kiosk application using flex swf(not Adobe air). Is there a way to include an on-screen keyboard(a virtual keyboard is automatically displayed) for all form items in the application for every [view state](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63611-7ffa.html) wherever there is a [form](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextInput.html)/[textfield](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextArea.html) etc element. This is quite similar to android/ios apps where the OS pops up a keyboard wherever required for such controls?

Comment: Are you asking whether its possible to do such a thing or whether there's already an implementation of such a thing?

Comment: Hi @iceman, I took the liberty of merging your two nearly identical questions.

Comment: @Lasse:thanks,somehow the submit post went twice!!is it possible to delete the duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Active den has an on-screen keyboard for purchase [here](http://activeden.net/item/as3-keyboard-onscreen/30799), or there is a tutorial [here](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/711/1/AS3-On-Screen-Keyboard/Page1.html) on actionscript.org.

Comment: The code in the second link make heavy use of statics, which makes it hard to integrate into some apps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `needsSoftKeyboard="true"` on your inputs.  There's a good example of the usage of the soft keyboard [here](http://www.kerkness.ca/flex-on-screen-qwerty-keyboard-component/).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.uibuzz.com/2011/adobe/flex/github-flex-4-component-virtualkeyboard/

https://github.com/GrfxGuru/Adobe-Flex-4.5-Components

The component dispatches an event back to the application with the label of the key you pressed that you can then use as needed.